# Python webview in a maximized window

Tags: python, tkinter, webview, pywebview

I am trying to show a local html page in pywebview in a maximized screen by default , I have tried all methods I could find but it didnt work.
here is my code :

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import threading
import webview
import os
 
...

webview.create_window('My React App', url='http://127.0.0.1:5000')
webview.start()
```

**here is what I have tried so far:**

1. I tried Fullscreen flag as True but it will only show the webview in full screen and the windows frame around the webview disappears, I am trying to show it as a maximized window with "close , minimize etc" buttons

   `webview.create_window('My React App', url='http://127.0.0.1:5000', fullscreen=True)`
2. Then I tried to get the screen size and define that as height and width , it maximized the window  but it showed 10 pixel gap on the right and left side of the window :

   ```
   screen_width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
   screen_height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

   root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")


   webview.create_window("My React App",url="http://127.0.0.1:5000",width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
   ```

**How can I make it so , that it launched the webview in a maximized window by default?**

Answer (score 0):

In webview, maximize functionality is not available by default.

You can try `fullscreen` option of the `webview.create_window()` method.

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import threading
import webview
import os
 
...

webview.create_window('My React App', url='http://127.0.0.1:5000', fullscreen=True)
webview.start()
```